# Maximal aggregate loss in Risk Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process, actuarial-science

I am studying the Crámer Lundberg Risk Process. This process is defined as follows:
$$Y_t=r_0+ct-Z_t$$
Where $Z_t$ is a compound Poisson sum, it means that $Z_t=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{N_t} X_i$, where $N_t$ is a Poisson process, and $X_t$ are i.i.d random variables that follows a distribution $F$.

Then is defined the maximal aggregate loss, that is:
$$S=\sup_{t\geq 0}\{Z_t-ct\}$$

I am trying to simulate this kind of risk process, but I am not clear with the supremum. For that reason, I have been looking some extra information on the maximal aggregate loss. I found in a pdf (file:///C:/Users/lenovo/Downloads/LefevreTrufinZuyderhoff2017_Diffusion.pdf)
 in page 4 the next expression:

[image]

That is an equivalent way to compute the maximal aggregate loss that I am interested in. 
However, I can't see how to prove it.

I think that using this equivalence in R will be easier for me because I need to compute the maximum, in the first expression with the supremum is not so direct because I know that the supremum is the smaller superior bound, it means that the supremum can´t be in the considered set.

Any help with the proof of the equality?

Comment: You might fix the `Lefevre Trufin` pdf link from your `local file` to https://dipot.ulb.ac.be/dspace/bitstream/2013/258727/3/LefevreTrufinZuyderhoff2017_Diffusion.pdf

Comment: if you're asking for a proof of the equality, you might want to define the $T_i$

Comment: $T_i$ is the time between two consecutivo arrivals, under this framework is an exponential random variable, since is a compound poisson process.